Config routing Softether VPN for connect DB by card vpn and config access internet by card eth0
I setup Softether VPN client on centos 7.
After setting up VPN, I saw my IP change to the IP of the server VPN.
I want to connect DB by VPN and other connections to my Server using card eth0.
Can you help me config IP routing?
enter image description here

Does this answer your question? Softether. Clients can connect but I can't access the server
